# Trying to make re-usable function by passing Object in Realm, gives error

Tags: swift, realm, reusability

so I am trying to make a re-usable function, where I pass the object (I have 3 Object classes), but when I try the code below, the code barks at me that `value of type object has no member id`. It shows this at the line of code: `arrayFromDB.append(items.id)`

It's weird because all 3 of my Objects contain id

```
func deleteUnwanted (fromJSON:[Int], db: Object.Type) {
    var arrayFromDB:[Int] = [Int]()
    let realm = try! Realm()
    let getFromDB = realm.objects(db)
    for items in getFromDB {
        arrayFromDB.append(items.id)
    }
... other stuff
```

The call itself to the function (which doesn't give errors)

```
self.deleteUnwanted(self.catstringJson,db: LocalDataFolders.self)
```

The Object classes

```
class LocalDataF: Object {

    dynamic var id:Int = 0
    ...

    override static func primaryKey() -> String? {
        return "id"
    }
}

class LocalDataC: Object {
    dynamic var id:Int = 0
    ...

    override static func primaryKey() -> String? {
        return "id"
    }
}

class LocalDataA: Object {
    dynamic var id:Int = 0
    ...

    override static func primaryKey() -> String? {
        return "id"
    }
}
```

Comment: I know nothing of Realm but it seems like you're wanting a generic function.  If so it should be defined as: `func deleteUnwanted<T>(fromJSON: [Int], db: T.Type)` , by using `Object.Type` you are effectively just using `Object`.  Also you must define a type or protocol that has the `id` property and then constrain the generic parameter to that in order to access the `id` inside the function.

Comment: When I try this, it gives back `Cannot convert value of type 'T.Type' to expected argument type 'Object.Type'`  on the line `let getFromDB = realm.objects(db)`
The type will always be of Object, so I'm not sure if I should make it generic either. It can have 3 different Objects, nothing else.

Comment: Maybe you can try `func deleteUnwanted<T: Object>...` to constrain it to always being an Object, but even then you wont be able to access the `id` property without casting to a type that has an `id` property.

Comment: still keep having issues with Object and Object.Type. I think it's a Realm issue.

Answer (score 1):

Realm DB has nothing to do with your problem.

Swift is not a duck-typed language. You do know that all your objects has `id` fields, but you also have to find a way to convince the compiler they do.

```
protocol HasId {

    associatedtype IdType

    var id: IdType { get }

}

struct A: HasId {
    var id: Int = -1
}

struct B: HasId {
    var id: Int = -1
}

func listIds<T: HasId>(items: [T]) {
    print(items.map { $0.id })
}

listIds([A(id: 1), A(id: 2), A(id: 3)]) // [1, 2, 3]
listIds([B(id: 4), B(id: 5), B(id: 6)]) // [4, 5, 6]
```